# Damaged or frozen script on website, how to find it?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am getting a message sometimes in Firefox, which says that a script is frozen or damaged. The script which the dialog mentions is:

```
http://example.com/:1
```

I can not reproduce the dialog at the moment, but the :1 looks suspicious. What could that mean?

The message in Firefox is similiar to this one: *A script on this page may be busy, or It may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.*

Thanks!

Comment: The `:1` just tells you its line number 1, where the error occured. Everytime in further JS debugging it gives you via the `:` the line in which the error occured. But I doubt this actually helps finding your damaged/frozen script. For further help we would need more details/code.

Comment: Yeah, but why isnt it saying in which JavaScript file? I do not have any code, I was given the task to eliminate this error.

Comment: Maybe on your page there is inline script? That's why having the actual code would be very helpfull for further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If a JavaScript error has a colon followed by a number, the number is what line in the script that caused the error.

For example, `foo-bar.js:57` means the error occurred on the 57th line in "foo-bar.js".

The reason why your error says `http://example.com/` is because the server of "example.com" is configured to display the home-page without saying "/home.html" in the URL, so you don't see anything after the "/". The JavaScript of "example.com" is probably inline, so it doesn't say `http://example.com/script.js:1` either.

* I used fake examples for the "example.com" thing.